# Can't add shared drive as Time Machine drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

Solved by [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250732013?answerId=251436244022#251436244022). Can't post as answer due to low reputation on this network site.

> - on the server (in my case the iMac) in the settings --> sharing tab, disable file sharing (no need to reboot or whatever)
> - on the "client" side (the machine from which you want to access the external TM drive mounted on the server) force restart the finder app (via "--> Force Quit" menu
> - re-activate the file sharing on the server again.

---

I have a Mac Mini on my network with an external hard drive mounted on it. I use this external drive for Time Machine for a couple computers.

All was well until today, when I got a new Mac Mini. I migrated all my stuff over to the new machine, mounted my backup disk and tried to add it as the Time Machine backup drive in my Macbook Pro. I get the following error:

> Time Machine can’t connect to the backup disk.
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 13.)

I've tried a number of troubleshooting tips. Restarted both machines, restarted the external enclosure, even reformatted the backups drive (nothing important was lost... I hope).

As a *possible* hint to a root problem, `Finder -> Go -> Network -> [Computer] -> Backups` raises an error as well:

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Backups” can’t be found.

Both machines are running macOS 10.15.

Comment: Did you use macOS Server (and its Time Machine Server) or standard File Sharing (+ “Share as a Time Machine backup destination.”) previously?

Comment: Was the drive encrypted or password protected?

Comment: Previously I used macOS Server. No, the drive is not encrypted or password protected.

Comment: Is it the same error when you try and reach the drive through the network folder?
If you mount a different hard drive to the mac mini and try and access it from your Macbook Pro, is that working?

Comment: I have two partitions on the same physical drive. The other one seems to have some very strange permissions errors, with folders with 777 permissions being invisible to applications running under the same account with which I access them via the finder.

Comment: What do you mean "shared drive"? Is it used via Network or connected directly instead?

Comment: Physically connected to and mounted on another mac and accessed via the network using SMB.

Comment: I was getting so frustrated trying to solve this exact issue, you just saved my mac from being thrown out the window!

Comment: This "answer" solved my problem as well (I chose to log out and back in again instead of force-quitting the Finder).